# Can I add a dynamic condition for AWS load balancer to automatically add new instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Is there a way like assigning a specific tag for the EC2 instances to automatically attached to the load balancer on AWS?
I believe I had done that in the past but unable to find that option now.

Comment: What sort of conditions you mean ? Usually you do this by going to the load balancer section in the portal and in “Add EC2 Instances” page. Alternatively, you can script this.

Comment: Yes, I can select the instances from Load balancer options. But let's assume if some external service is launching those new EC2 instances. Is there a way to launch those EC2 instances with a tag like "key=type, value=for-load-balancer" and AWS will automatically register or de-register those EC2 instances based on this tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you've done it in the past, I believe you're thinking of a feature offered by EC2 auto-scaling groups (ASGs).  ASG is a capability of the EC2 infrastructure that scales machine counts up and down based on workload or maintains a set number of healthy instances always running (destroying and replacing failed instances).  When an ASG is attached to a load balancer, the instances controlled by the ASG are automatically registered and deregistered from the balancer.

> Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling integrates with Elastic Load Balancing to enable you to attach one or more load balancers to an existing Auto Scaling group. After you attach the load balancer, it automatically registers the instances in the group and distributes incoming traffic across the instances.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/attach-load-balancer-asg.html